# how to call on a new line in ReadFields?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textfieldparser

In ASP.net vb, I am reading a .txt file and want to assign a variable to each field in the file. So far I have

```
Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("SomePath\SomeFile.txt")

MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")

Dim currentRow As String()
currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields
A1 = currentRow(0)
A2 = currentRow(1)
A3 = currentRow(2)
```

I have three fields in each row, so this allows me to assign variables to the 3 fields in the first row which are separated by commas. However, I am having difficulty accessing the next row to create new variables for the following fields. Any ideas how I could assign variables to all the fields in this .txt file? I am very new to this so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, you're not assigning variables to the fields. You're assigning the data from the fields to the variables. The `=` is the assignment operator and you assign what is on the right to what is on the left. It's just like mathematics.

Comment: As for the question, you can't, unless you know exactly how many lines the file will contain. Doing so wouldn't make sense in the vast majority of cases anyway. What does this data represent and what are you actually trying to do with it? If you explain that then we can explain the best way to achieve it. Most like you should create a `List(Of T)` where `T` is some type that will contain the three values from a row. That might be an array or a dedicated type with three properties.

Comment: this data represents different calibration names for an equation and 2 constants that go with the calibrations. for example, "name date", 1, 2 would be one row in the txt file, all other rows following similarly, and I need to assign variables to the data in all 3 of those fields, for 5 rows. I want to be able to then call on these variables so that I can put the calibration name in a dropdown bar and create a program in which users can select the calibration name they would like to use, and I will calculate an answer for them using the constants associated with the calibration name selected

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("SomePath\SomeFile.txt")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Dim currentRow() As String
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields
            A1 = currentRow(0)
            A2 = currentRow(1)
            A3 = currentRow(2)
        End While
    End Using
```

edit based on comment

```
            Dim currentRow() As String
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields
            A1 = currentRow(0)
            A2 = currentRow(1)
            A3 = currentRow(2)

            'repeat as many times as necessary to get to 15 vars 

            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields
            A4 = currentRow(0)
            A5 = currentRow(1)
            A6 = currentRow(2)
```

Comment: wouldn't this just rewrite over those variable names? like at the end, wouldn't there still only be three variables, A1, A2, and A3 with whatever values were most recently assigned to it

Comment: @ameliazaripova - yes.  You didn't show other variables or give an idea of how many variables.

Comment: I have 5 rows, each containing 3 fields of data. In total I would need 15 variables. My question is how can I move on to the next row in my txt file? Is there some way I can call on row 1, 2, 3, etc. or is that not possible

Comment: @ameliazaripova - see my edit based on your comments.  I feel like there is something you aren't telling us, but I've been wrong before.